# Travel from and to UK with two passports, one of which contains a UK permanent residency

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, morocco, moroccan-citizens

I have 2 Moroccan passports, one is out of date, but has the indefinite leave of remain visa, the other up to date. I did this before, travel from Morocco to UK using this method, but they asked too many questions in Morocco, not so much when I landed here. I wanted to ask for sure, can they take my old passport (it has my indefinite residency) I don't want to risk going there and not being able to return due to the Moroccan border control not understanding the job. I checked on the British Home Office site and it's OK.

Comment: Why are you even showing the old passport to Morrocan immigration?

Comment: Why would you even need to show the old passport _returning to Morocco_? The current one ought to be quite enough for a citizen to return home.

Comment: [Transfer your visa to a new passport](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa) has some useful information. It may be worth getting a biometric residence permit so that you don't have to deal with the two passports.

Comment: Well, going in from the UK is fine, i know that. But coming back, they won't let me leave without a Visa. I have to go immediately, and getting it transferred will take a while

Comment: The immigration people require seeing the visa? I know that the airline will normally ask for it (because they get fined if you don't have one), but why does exit immigration care?

Comment: Since the question is about a permanent residency, it's much better to relocate this to Expats.SE.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Just because the person who's taveling is not living in his country of origin doesn't mean that the travel he does from wherever-he-lives isn't traveling!

Comment: @HenningMakholm OP is traveling to a country where he is an Expat and the question is only relevant to Moroccan expats in the UK, though.